# Creating random disjoint subarrays from an array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

So I have an array of 'a' to 'j' as follows

```
initarray: Array<any> = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
```

I would like to create three subarrays in which a character can only be used one. For example

```
rand1: Array<any> = ['a','b','c'];
rand2: Array<any> = ['g','h','j'];
rand3: Array<any> = ['e','f','i'];
```

Not all of the values in init array have to be used. How can I achieve this?

edit: adding more information to the question

So I have an array of food name, nutrition arrays.  For example

```
food_name: Array<any> = [‘a’,’b’,’c’,’d’,’e’,’f’,’g’,’h’,’i’,’j’];
protein_val: Array<any> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
carb_val: Array<any> = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
fat_val: Array<any> = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
```

I want to random three arrays in which the elements are not the same

for example

```
randfood1: Array<any> = ['a','b','c'];
randfood2: Array<any> = ['g','h','j'];
randfood3: Array<any> = ['e','f','i'];
```

the randfood1 randfood2 randfood3 will be the set of randomed food name

I also want the nutrition array randomed with the same index from the original array. For instance

```
randprotein1: Array<any> = [1,2,3];    
randcarb1: Array<any> = [4,5,6];
randfat1: Array<any> = [7,8,9];
```

corresonding to

```
randfood1: Array<any> = ['a','b','c'];
```

which will match the index of a,b,c from the food_name array

Comment: Do you do something with your initial array? Is it dynamic?

Comment: @distante If possible, I'd like the initial array to be the same. But if it's necessary to delete some elements, it's ok too.

Comment: Yet another question @karn-piriyapanya , do you want that `typescript` generate the random array ? How are you generating the rand? Typescript can not interact with run time process.

Comment: Yes, currently, I have the random function written but it doesn't make unique arrays. However, I'll edit the question hoping to make my question more clear. Sorry for being ambigious